# Submitting a form via AJAX that redirects to a different page?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a search section on my site that runs across each page. I am attempting to jQuery/AJAX to capture the data input in the search and process the information and display the returned information on the search results page on my site.

Here is the search section HTML:

```
           <div id="search">
                <form action="/search/" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Query" autocomplete="off" id="search-q">
                <input type="submit">
                </form>
            </div>
```

Within my JavaScript for the site, I have this code:

```
    $(document).on("submit", "#search form", function(){
        var a = $("#search-q").val(); //Gets the variable for the search
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/ajax/search",
                data: "q=" + a,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function() { $("div#loading").show(); },
                complete: function() { $("div#loading").hide(); },
                success: function(data) {
                    //process of returned data
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
```

The issue that I am running into is that when the form is submitted via jQuery, it is trying to display the search results on whatever page you are doing the search, versus having the site goto the `/search/` page for the search results.

Any ideas?

Comment: try using full absolute path in URL

Comment: try not using AJAX....Why use AJAX if you are going to redirect them to another page

Comment: Have you tried looking into jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load in the data from the query page, into the desired object model?

Comment: You could use as ajax option `context: this,` and then in success callback: `this.submit();`  but **why**???

Comment: If you are going to handle the data submission with jQuery, then don't use a form. Or, at least, use `e.preventDefault();` at top, and `return false;` at bottom of your function

Comment: @B Days - That was my original intent, to not use AJAX, but some of the search queries are pretty intensive, so I would much rather have a page load and let the AJAX works behind the scenes to bring up the results, than having a page loading in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in success function of ajax

`window.location.href = "yoururl";`

or

`window.location.replace= "yoururl";`

Answer (score 0):

not sure why would you want to use Ajax if you just redirect the page after ajax response. I can't see any point of using ajax.

But anyway,

You can do something like this,

```
    $(document).on("submit", "#search form", function(){
        var a = $("#search-q").val(); //Gets the variable for the search
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/ajax/search",
                data: "q=" + a,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function() { $("div#loading").show(); },
                complete: function() { $("div#loading").hide(); },
                success: function(data) {
                    window.location.replace("URLyouwanttoreirect" + encodeURI(data) );
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
```

You can also pass another query var on the url redirected, and on that URL, do some stuff to check if they are redirected from ajax request then process the data that is included on the URL.

If you want all your search to be redirect on specific search result page, you can have a form like this,

```
<form method="get" action="http://site1231.com/search">
        <input type="text" value="" name="search" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />          
</form>
```

when its submitted, it will give you this url

`http://site1231.com/search?search=Keyword`

You can then process the result based on that search var, and you don't need jQuery/Ajax

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but you could probably (as your page is using the GET method), load in the data by this simple jQuery.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#search form", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    var a = $("#search-q").val(); //Gets the variable for the search
        $("#data-output").load("/search?q=" + a, function() {
            $(this).find("#data-output").unwrap(); // Load drops the new div into the other div, so you want to unwrap it aswell.
        });
    return false;
});
```

I'd like to know if it works, as I am not really into this but tried my best to help you anyways.